# Minor Problem of Encryption and Decryption

Tags: c#, encryption

- This is the Encryption and Decryption program *
  In C#
  The program is workable and able to execute to pop out a Windows Application Form but the problem is after i press START button and there is no result shows to me that the file has been encrypted to the new Path that i choose. Is it any problem inside the code ?

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.IO;

  namespace Advanced_Encryption_Decryption
  {
      public partial class EncryptDecrypt : Form
  {
      byte[] abc;
      byte[,] table;

      public EncryptDecrypt()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
          od.Multiselect = false;
          if(od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
          {
              tbPath.Text = od.FileName;
          }
      }

      private void btnEncryption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if(rbEncryption.Checked)
          {
              rbDecryption.Checked = false;
          }
      }

      private void btnDecryption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (rbDecryption.Checked)
              rbEncryption.Checked = false;
      }

      private void EncryptDecrypt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          rbEncryption.Checked = true;

          //Initialize ABC and Table
          abc = new byte[256];
          for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
              abc[i] = Convert.ToByte(i);

          table = new byte[256, 256];
          for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
              for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
              {
                  table[i, j] = abc[(i + j) % 256];
              }
      }

      private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          //Check Input Values
          if(!File.Exists(tbPath.Text))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist");
              return;
          }

          if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPassword.Text))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Password Empty. PLease Enter Your Password");
              return;
          }

          //Encryption and Decryption

          //Get File Content and Key for Encryption or Decryption
          try
          {
              byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(tbPath.Text);
              byte[] passwordTmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tbPassword.Text);
              byte[] keys = new byte[fileContent.Length];
              for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
                  keys[i] = passwordTmp[i % passwordTmp.Length];

              //Encryption
              byte[] result = new byte[fileContent.Length];

              if (rbEncryption.Checked)
              {

                  for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
                  {
                      byte value = fileContent[i];
                      byte key = keys[i];
                      int valueIndex = -1, keyIndex = -1;
                      for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                          if (abc[j] == value)
                          {
                              valueIndex = j;
                              break;
                          }
                      for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                          if (abc[j] == key)
                          {
                              keyIndex = j;
                              break;
                          }

                      result[i] = table[keyIndex, valueIndex];
                  }
              }
              //Decryption
              else
              {
                  for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
                  {
                      byte value = fileContent[i];
                      byte key = keys[i];
                      int valueIndex = -1, keyIndex = -1;
                      for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                          if (abc[j] == value)
                          {
                              valueIndex = j;
                              break;
                          }
                      for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                          if (table[keyIndex, j] == value)
                          {
                              valueIndex = j;
                              break;
                          }

                      result[i] = abc[valueIndex];
                  }
              }

              //Save Result to New File with the SAME EXTENTION
              String fileExt = Path.GetExtension(tbPath.Text);
              SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
              sd.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExt + ") | *" + fileExt;
              if(sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {
                  File.WriteAllBytes(sd.FileName, result);
              }
          }

          catch
          {
              MessageBox.Show("File is IN USE. Close other program is using 
              this file and TRY AGAIN");
              return;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint to see if Start method is actually called?

Comment: I hope you're aware that this in "Encryption", not Encryption. Maybe suitable for protecting your secrets from your little sister, but that's about it.

Comment: This won't help your actual problem but you should `catch (Exception ex)`, then display the actual error message, or if you want that to be the message when the file is in use catch that particular Exception type and have another more generic catch which displays or logs the actual error. At the moment you're losing your actual error info which won't help.

Comment: Do you run `EncryptDecrypt_Load()` somewhere? It seems you need to do it, otherwise you will get errors long before you want to show results.

Comment: Maybe a bit premature hint, but please try and put the business logic code (the file reading / encryption) in a separate class from the GUI code. You'll thank me later if you do. Programming is all about decomposing problems and composing applications.